# resources under drawable cannot be recognized by R

Tags: android, android-resources, android-drawable

I have the following file which cannot be recongized by R. The unrecognized file is arrow2.png. The code is as following

in **pkg2**

```
Marker instructionMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.arrow2)) //This is where it fails to recognize resource
                                                        .flat(true)
                                                        .position(instructionAnchorPoint)
                                                        .snippet(instruction+"--"+distance));
```

The File directory as following

```
project
    /src
        /pkg1_mainpkg
            some java files
        /pkg2
            some java files
        /pkg3
            some java files
    /gen
        /pkg4
            R.java
        /pkg1_mainpkg
            R.java (contains the id for "arrow2", defined as **public static final int arrow2=0x7f020000;**)


    /res
        /drawable-hdpi
            arrow2.png
            ...
        /drawable-ldpi
            arrow2.png
            ...
        /drawable-mdpi
            arrow2.png
            ...
        /layout
        /values
```

Comment: your import is probably wrong. you probably import android.R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are probably importing android.R.

you need to import your project package like

import com.example.yourproject.R;

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean your project and rebuild it. You can, even, delete all contents under gen dir and rebuild everything.